# How to limit recursive function in PHP

Tags: php, function, recursion, limit

This recursive function saturates the memory of my browser because it calls all the children of the tree in order to create a flowchart. So I'm looking for a way to limit the recursion

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($rq)>0) {
    $kid = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rq);
    $sq = "SELECT groupe_id FROM groupe_tbl WHERE groupe_groupe_id=$groupe_id";
    $rq = IPT_query($sq);
    
    if(mysqli_num_rows($rq)>0){
        $kid['kids'] = array();
        while($k=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rq)) {
            $kid['kids'][] = get_kids($k['groupe_id']);
        }
    } else $kid['kids'] = false;
    return $kid;
```

I tried to limit the number of children with this. But this only limits the number of children to load and therefore does not solve my problem.

```
while($i<20 and $k=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rq)) {
    $kid['kids'][] = get_kids($k['groupe_id']); $i++;
```

Comment: read the concept of `LIMIT` in query and use that

Comment: Do you mean the total number of children (i.e. including already loaded) or can you limit it by the levels that you load (this allows you to try and implement lazy loading).

Comment: @NigelRen I would like to limit the number of children loaded directly on the recursive function

Answer (score 0):

limiting the recursion is not a thing about PHP, the basic idea when you are writing a recursion function is to set a condition that tells the function when it **SHOULD** stop being recursion.

based on if you are using oop methods or procedural functions.

but you can achieve it with something like this:

```
function get_kids ($limit = 1) {
    if ($limit > 10) {
        return false;
    }

    echo $limit . "\n";

    $limit++;
    get_kids($limit);
}

get_kids(1);
```

or if you are using oop you can use the previous approach or the following approach:

```
class class1
{
    public $limit = 1;

    public function get_kids()
    {
        if ($this->limit > 10) return false;

        echo $this->limit . "\n";

        $this->limit++;
        $this->get_kids();
    }
}

$x = new class1;
$x->get_kids();
```

Comment: I use the first method but I can't integrate it into my code it's the first time I deal with recursvie functions. I already have a function named : ``function get_kids($groupe_id, $limit = 1)`` I added the limit variable to it but I don't see how to do the rest